# Selecting with query where conditions are met for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

Say I have a dataframe in Pandas consisting of several columns. I would like to select the subset of the dataframe where **all** columns are between two values `min` and `max`.

How can I do this using [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)? Do I need to specify every column name one by one in the expression e.g.:

```
df.query('(A<{max} & A>{min}) & (B{min} & B{max}) & (C{min} & C{max})'.format(min,max))
```

Aside from query, what other alternatives do I have? Perhaps working with the indices where the condition is met directly?

Comment: Since your question is pretty value, an answer will have to be very vague. Show us what exactly you'd write with `query` specifying every column name one by one (and with example data, too), and someone can hopefully show you how to write it without doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your use case I'd do it the non-query way, constructing a boolean frame and then calling the `.all` method:

```
>>> minval, maxval = 20, 80
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (20,6)))
>>> df[((df > minval) & (df < maxval)).all(axis=1)]
     0   1   2   3   4   5
2   74  30  30  76  31  66
10  49  39  71  43  30  50
```

I don't think the advantage of manually constructing an expanded `query` would be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you think you need `query` here. But if you want to do it this way, you can. You're already building up the query string dynamically with that `format` statement; you just need to make it *more* dynamic, by joining a comprehension. For example:

```
qs = ' & '.join('{col}<{max} & {col}>{min}'.format(col, min, max)
                for col in df.columns)
df.query(qs)
```

I would personally do this the way @DSM suggested instead. Unless you actually need the query string for some reason (maybe to print it out?), building a string to eval it as an expression, instead of building an expression, is usually the wrong answer.